# What would happen if 90% of the population had learning problems

Tags: society, diseases, education

Lets say a terrorist group developed a prion or something similar that when it was introduced into a human brain caused things to start backfiring and rewiring. They released a large enough quantity of it undetected that it went around the world and infected everyone.

90% of the population gains [learning disabilities](https://ldaamerica.org/types-of-learning-disabilities/) ranging from dyslexia, ADHD, auditory processing disorder, executive functioning, etc. These range from 40% minor, 40% moderate, and 20% being severe. 
This also passes onto future generations at the same rate.

How badly would this affect civilization?

Comment: In most of Africa, most of the population has an IQ that is low by First World standards.  A few African countries are developing economically, especially if they welcome businesses based in more developed parts of the world to run industries, construction projects, and logistical operations.  But most African countries are in poor shape.

Comment: It would definitely improve parliaments the world over.  That's, what, a 100% improvement on government now ? :-)

Comment: Looking around it seems we may be a large way into that world already.

Comment: @Jasper That claim sounds odd.  Could we have a link to your source ?

Comment: @StephenG, IQ tests generally have under developed and developing countries ranked lower, sometimes much lower than developed countries. The problem is that IQ is better for measuring the education and knowledge of a person rather than the basic intelligence. Early IQ tests showed how as Western countries increased their education levels the IQ tests increased dramatically, which is why new IQ tests raise the standards so that we don't see people with 300 IQ points or more. So comparing China or the US to most African countries is like comparing a regular person against an Olympian.

Comment: lol, honestly I do not see why something should change, it basically as it is today or maybe 200-500 years ago.

Comment: @StephenG -- It is actually very well documented, but (for obvious political reasons) often vigorously denied.  https://iq-research.info/en/page/average-iq-by-country has a tabular summary, *caveats*, and links to sources.  It provides a single average number per country, which is inappropriate for countries like South Africa that still have large white populations.

Comment: @MolbOrg, in the US, even with the over eagerness to apply disability status to children, only 4% of school aged children are diagnosed with a learning disability.

Comment: I've personally always regarded IQ tests as worse than useless, although Dan Clarke's comment does suggest they may be (accidentally) useful as indicators of how much "reach" the education systems in countries have.  I wonder if anyone has looked for a correlation between e.g. GDP per capita and these IQ scores - something to do for the weekend, I suppose. :-)

Comment: @StephenG, I see IQ tests as a useful measure between schools in the same country. If one school is particularly low, it has a serious problem. But between countries... ugh.

Comment: IQ has remarkably little to do with learning difficulties such as dyslexia, ADHD, reduced auditory or executive functioning. IQ results measure the capacity of persons to do well on IQ tests. The IQ issue is a red herring with respect to the OP's question.

Comment: To be facetious the unaffected ten percent should commit suicide to avoid the extreme frustration of trying to keep the world going. This would leave the terrorists in charge. Let them cope with the insanely impossible and unmanageable world they made.

Comment: @a4android, yep, which is why I basically ignored the whole stupid IQ issue. Last time I got involved in it I had to explain to the person that according to his links Asians had higher IQ than Whites, so he really shouldn't talk about superiority. Didn't work. And thanks, I liked your facetious answer.

Comment: Learning problems are relative. If 90% have what we would now call 'learning problems' then the larger percentage of those would be considered as 'normal' and the 10% with no problems would be considered as 'gifted'. There would be a percentage who would be considered as, against the adjusted norm, to have learning difficulties, but in terms of a percentage of the population, they are unlikely to differ much from what they are now.

Comment: By "executive functioning", do you mean executive *dys*function?

Comment: @F1Krazy, the website I linked to had it as executive functioning, so I'm sticking with it. But I was thrown a little bit by the name as well.

Comment: @DanClarke it was more about that 5% of scientist do publish half of all publications. Generally, a small percentage in each field does most of the work which moves the development. The proportion is observed in different types of activities. But sure it depends how severe are those disabilities. For sure it will be a shty situation, a lot of folks will die.

Comment: IQ debates are almost always wrongheaded -- unless competent psychologists are involved. I wanted to defuse the IQ nonsense, at least, it seems to have gone off the boil. I'm glad you appreciated the humour of my facetious answer which I posted as a comment. I didn't want to detract from the serious answers to your question. You have created a *real nightmare* world here.

Comment: @a4android, I'm looking for a nightmare world. I have to have some reason to make a colony fall hard alongside disease and war. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be an interesting world. If your terrorists did not follow up with starting a war and just let society continue as it would, then people with learning disabilities would be suddenly the norm. You say these would not be uniform, so it is likely that education and communication would evolve in a lot of different, specialised ways to help these distinct groups of people communicate better and function better within a society.

People with learning disabilities aren't any less clever than people without. They are just slower because our education and communication systems evolved to work fastest with people who can use them well. But I suspect as more and more people would be affected with not being able to function well within the existing system, there would be more and more innovations on the field of alternative communication systems. And soon what was seen as disability to function in a world normalized for one way to think and communicate would develop into heightened abilities to function in alternatively specialised environments.

A kind of caste system would probably evolve that groups together people with certain kinds of abilities. These abilities would soon to be identified as best suited in certain fields of science or art or vocation and maybe it would evolve into one of those recently popular Y.A. tropes where society is divided into pre-defined groups - which may or may not turn into a dystopia, depending on a lot of factors, really, but mostly on the author's decision to make it one or not.

All in all, I'd love to see where a world like this would go.

Answer (score 3):

> 90% of the population gains learning disabilities ranging from dyslexia, ADHD, auditory processing disorder, executive functioning, etc.
>
> These range from 40% minor, 40% moderate, and 20% being severe. This also passes onto future generations at the same rate.
>
> How badly would this affect civilization?

Depending on how wealthy your country is and how committed it is to social medicine I think the results would be different.

Countries that can afford increased health and education costs might see little change, beyond an increase in taxes to cover the expenses.  Countries without socialized medicine systems would see either increases in private health insurance costs or might suffer the effects of not investing in proper care.

Poorer countries would likely suffer increases in poverty levels (as these problems will all reduce the capacity of individuals and society as a whole to generate income).

As there's a clear link between poverty and crime you would have to expect that the poorer parts of any society would, once again, bare the brunt of the effects, suffering increased poverty, increased crime as both victim and perpetrators.  They would be the least able to cope and the most likely to suffer the resultant knock-on effects of debt and increased risk of serious health problems and shorter lives.

Civilization, as such, would continue.  There would be changes, all negative.  It would probably not be catastrophic in the long term, although a sudden onset of these problems on a population wide basis would drastically reduce the effectiveness of most government services and agencies in the short term.  Again in the short term there could be a drastic shortage of skilled personal who can work at normal capacity.

Governments are generally designed to be robust to personal loss.  Although the loss of a lot of people in a short period would cause problems, it would not cause too many as government and even the military and police are, in many ways, procedurally organized and while standards might drop for a while, they would not be crippled.

On the plus side, BrExit negotiations are so screwed up that the can't really get worse, and Congress can't agree a budget *now* so no change at all in Washington. :-)

In the longer term there would probably be an even greater deepening of the rich-poor pay gap, as the demand for skilled and effective workers would generally exceed supply in this scenario.  However they'd probably be taxed or levied one way or another to cover the costs for society as a whole, so I suspect they would not be getting substantially richer anyway.

In the longer, longer term there would clearly be medical research to find a cure

Over the medium term I'd expect most governments to develop enough emergency measures to cope.  Medium term would be e.g. a year or two.

> Lets say a terrorist group developed a prion or something similar that when it was introduced into a human brain caused things to start backfiring and rewiring. They released a large enough quantity of it undetected that it went around the world and infected everyone.

Socially an attack of the sort you describe might result in a more unified global view.  While you'd not expect it to make friends of long term enemies, you could reasonably expect that everyone would unite to some extent at least against the common threat and similar threats.

However these kind of alliances generally do not lead to long term connections (think about the Allies and the Soviets after WW2).   So essentially this kind of attack would be a disaster for the people making it, as they'll get the undivided attention of the entire planet, but it would be business as usual for everyone else (e.g. we're all going to continue hating our neighbors :-)).